# TPM Non-Volatile Memory Size?

Tags: tpm, non-volatile

I am using IBM TPM v1332 + IBM TSS v1470 now and trying to store some essential keywords/passwords to non-volatile memory on TPM. 
I found two ways to do so. One is to create a sealed object and use `evictcontrol` to store it, like:

`${PREFIX}evictcontrol -ho $objHandle -hp 81800002 -hi p`

Another way is using NV command directly to store something:

`${PREFIX}nvdefinespace -hi o -ha 01000000 -pwdn nnn
${PREFIX}nvwrite -ha 01000000 -pwdn nnn`

However, I couldn't find any information about the non-volatile spaces available in TPM. Is this described in the TPM spec? Where could I find the information? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TPM PC platform specification](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/pc-client-platform-tpm-profile-ptp-specification/) says:

*"1.The TPM SHALL provide a minimum of 6962 (dec) bytes of NV Storage."*

If you use evictcontrol you should note that the TPM allows only a small number of persitstent objects at the same time (at least 7, of which 4 are reserved).
You can get the number of available persistent slots using the *TPM2_GetCapability* command with TPM_CAP_TPM_PROPERTIES as capability. TPM_PT_HR_PERSISTENT_AVAIL will be at least 1 if you can store another object.

The amount of available NV memory is device dependant, you have to check the data sheets. I suggest to work with the numbers from the PC platform specification, they are valid for every device.

Comment: I checked TPM_PT_HR_PERSISTENT_AVAIL on my TPM 2.0 simulator and got the number as 11. Do the specs mention about what the size of each slot is? I only saw spec says the number is an estimate (p50, TPM-Rev-2.0-Part-2-Structures-01.38.pdf)

Comment: I think there is no fixed size, because you can make different key types (with different sizes) persistent (ec, rsa,...).

Comment: Could I think those slots are part of NV storage defined in the specification (6962 byte)?? The spec says "The TPM Library Specification treats all non-volatile entities as part of the same pool of NV memory". Looks like it only defines a minimum NV size, but TPM vendors can decide what's the size for their persistent object/slots (usually a small size) + other NV storage.